# Override Vuetify v-icon color

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to override the default color of Vuetify icons with no luck.

```
.theme--light.v-icon {
    color: rgba(16, 24, 40, 0.54);
}
```

I've tried here

```
$material-light: (
  'icons': (
    'active': 'red',
    'inactive': 'red',
  ),
  'active-icon-percent': 0.80,
);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I've looked for ".54" value in Vuetify repository and those are the sole places where I've found it, I'm confused.

Any idea to set this color without brutally override it in css ?

Comment: what Vuetify version are you on?

Comment: version is 2.6.14

Comment: the variable $material-light was declared twice in SCSS files, the latter was overriding the first